# Converting XML to/from JSON in Java (strange message when using json-lib)

Tags: java, json

Why do I keep getting this message when trying to serialise an XML-string to JSON-string, when using Json-Lib.

Here is the code:

```
String jsonString = "<o><bool type=\"boolean\">true</bool>" +
                    "<int type=\"number\">1</int>" +
                    "<name type=\"string\">json</name></o>";
XMLSerializer xml = new XMLSerializer();
JSONObject jobject = (JSONObject) xml.read(jsonString);
System.out.println(jobject.toString(2));
```

Output is:

```
Sep 19, 2011 4:03:46 PM net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer getType
INFO: Using default type string
{
  "bool": true,
  "int": 1,
  "name": "json"
}
```

Why do I get this `“INFO: Using default...”` message? And, how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that message because your top level element o does not have a type. It's just an INFO message, so you can ignore it. If you changed:

```
<o>
```

to:

```
<o type="object">
```

It should go away. But, it also shouldn't matter.